# Typescript class inheritence

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to extend a base class and getting the following error:

> Class 'DerivedProduct' incorrectly extends base class 'BaseProduct'.
>   Types have separate declarations of a private property 'route'.

**Base Class:**

```
 export class BaseProduct {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store<fromState>){}
   }
```

**Derived Class:**

```
export class DerivedProduct extends BaseProduct {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store<fromState>){}
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: As a side note: I suppose the error should say `... DerivedProduct ..` instead of `DerivedClass`, isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fields are already declared in the base class so you don't need to redeclare them (ie no need to specify the modifier). Constructor arguments should just be arguments in the derived class and not fields. You also need to call the `super` constructor

```
export class BaseProduct {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store<fromState>) { }
}

export class DerivedProduct extends BaseProduct {
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, store: Store<fromState>) { 
        super(route, store)
    }
}
```

**Note** You could add extra fields using the constructor argument to field syntactic sugar but the base fields should not generally be re-declared. Public and protected fields generally would not cause issues if you re-declared them but you can't re-declared privates.

If you want to access those fields from the derived class change the modifier to `protected` or `public` in the base class.

**Edit**

As @series0ne points out  if you don't have any extra logic to the constructor you can omit it all together, as it will be inherited from the base class:

```
export class BaseProduct {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store<fromState>) { }
}

export class DerivedProduct extends BaseProduct {
}
new DerivedProduct(route, store); //Works, also Angular should see it like this as well.
```

Comment: Could the down-voter please comment as to the reason ? No judgement just want to know why you think the answer is not ok ..

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, I've just upvoted again because you are correct. Though, if I were you, I might add something about "if the constructor logic is the same in the derived class, you can just omit the constructor declaration from the derived class altogether"

Comment: @Dave The original version did not make them public, it kept them private to the base class.

Comment: @Dave Not specifying the access modifier on the derived constructor does not make them public fields, it makes them simple arguments. Keeping the fields private to the base class may be a reasonable approach, it's hard to say with just the provided sample.

Comment: Thanks but If I don't specify the modifier what are the parameters then public or private  and how they can be used from base as they are marked private? Can derived class access private props from base class ?

Comment: @Angad  If you want to access from the derived class change to `protected` in the base  class. If you don't  specify an access modifier the constructor argument is just an argument it does not become a field. You can have arguments to the constructor that are not fields just as you would for any other function,

Answer (score 1):

In both constructors, you use the keyword **private** on the route parameter. `private route: ActivatedRoute`.
When you use the `private` keyword, you are essentially saying that parameter in the constructor is also a member of your class. Thus `BaseProduct` has a member `route`, and you are also declaring the same in your `DerivedProduct`, which is why you are having the error.

**Solution**

Make route in `BaseProduct` protected

```
 export class BaseProduct {
    constructor(protected route: ActivatedRoute, protected store: Store<fromState>){}
}
```

Then in your derived class, do not use the private keyword, rather pass in your parameters to the `super` class.

```
export class DerivedProduct extends BaseProduct {
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, store: Store<fromState>){
       super(route, store);
       // this.route.doWhateverYouWantWithIt(this.store);....
    }
}
```

You will have access to both `route` and `store` as class members in both base and derived classes.